# How to display file upload progress using Angular Fire Modular and Firebase Storage in a Angular 17 project?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I am migrating an Angular 16 project to Angular 17 and changing over to @angular/fire from @angular/fire/compat.

I am able to upload files successfully however I cannot get my component to display the upload progress.

I am using

- @angular/core 17.3.1
- @angular/material 17.3.1
- @angular/fire 17.0.1

I am working off the upload example provided by [Firebase here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#full_example).

The Material progress bar does not update as intended.
Everything else works as it should (file is uploaded, console logs, etc).

Here is the pertinent code:

**upload.component.ts**

```
import { ref, Storage, uploadBytesResumable } from '@angular/fire/storage';

export class UploadComponent {
   constructor {private storage: Storage} ()

   progress:number = 0; //Used to display the file upload progress to the user
   uploadInProgress:boolean = false; //Used to toggle the visibility of the progress bar

   //Takes a file from an Input element and saves to Firebase Storage
   uploadFile(file: any) {      
      this.uploadInProgress = true;
      const fileRef = ref(this.storage, `storage/path/here`);

      uploadBytesResumable(fileRef, file).on('state_changed',
         (snapshot) => {
            //Log the progress to the console
            console.log('Uploading: ', snapshot.bytesTransferred, ' of ', snapshot.totalBytes, ' bytes');

            //Calculate and set the upload progress
            this.progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
         },
         (error) => {console.log(error);},
         () => {
            //Upload is complete
            this.uploadInProgress = false;
            this.progress = 0;
         }
      );
    }
```

**upload.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="this.uploadInProgress">
   <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="this.progress"></mat-progress-bar>                     
</ng-container>
```

I am sure it is something silly but I'm having a mental block and would appreciate some help.

Comment: You dont need to use 'this' in the template. ```[value]="progress"``` is enough. Try using a reactive approach like a subject or a signal instead of a plain variable.

Comment: I had tried the signal approach with no success. For example `progress = signal(0);` and `this.progress.set(x);` in the .ts and `[value]="progress()"` in the template.

Comment: Are you certain the progress is being reported? Try logging the value of progress after setting it. I cant identify anything odd by there is a non zero chance progress() === NaN

Comment: Yes. Using the signal approach, I console.log the starting progress `console.log(this.progress())`, then I calculate the new percentage and set the value `this.progress.set(percentage)`, then I log to the console again `console.log(this.progress())`.  Values are always correct and are always a number. Could I have missed something during the Angular upgrade from 16 to 17?